# Facebook API Graph reviews: I can't obtain the reviewer field

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I try to obtain all the informations about my page's reviews (I am the owner) with the API Graph but, when I use the exploration tool I can't obtain reviewer information.
My API call is:

{pageid}/ratings?fields=reviewer,review_text

but in the reviewer information I obtain "field is empty or disallowed by the access token"

Someone can help me?

Comment: are you sure that´s even possible? i would assume that it isn´t for privacy reasons, for example.

Comment: I can select this field in the field's list present in the exploration tool..but I don't know if something has changed..

Comment: a lot of things changed this year, regarding data privacy...so maybe that´s why

Comment: ok, but there isn't trace about it..

Comment: The documentation still lists the field "reviewer" in the recommendation Node but there seems to be no way of returning any data for it.  I don't get any errors it just returns nothing for that field. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/recommendation/